# Reply Urls - Azure AD B2C application - Limited to 20

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have  SaaS application and it is in beta stage. We will move to one URL in upcoming release. Now we are planning to go for a release where we need to add 30 URLs in Azure AD B2C. When I added 20 reply URLs, I get the below error:

> Application cannot have more than 20 reply URLs

This is no where in documentation about limitations of reply url. Can anyone help me to overcome this. How can I bypass this limitation? Will it be removed any time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**At this time, Azure AD B2C applications can only have 20 or less reply URLs.**

There is no workaround for this, you should request for this limit to be raised/removed via the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://aka.ms/aadb2cuv).

Comment: Are they willing to raise/remove that limit?

Comment: It looks like that limit has been raised to 45 now.
Screencap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB7Kn.png